# Using karma, angular-cache and the beforeEach Fn

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-cache

Good morning

I am trying to test our relatively big angular app with karma (or at least start with some tests). I got it to run with some minor troubles but am wondering now; karma offers a beforeEach function, which is called before every `it` code block.
When using angular, I (it seems so) have to call `module('app')` every time before executing one test case. Isn't that a total performance blocker? I mean setting up the whole module and therefore the app is a total waste of performance no?

When I place the module('app') call in a beforeAll() function I receive a
`Error: [$injector:unpr] Unknown provider: CacheFactoryProvider <- CacheFactory`

Did anyone experience that? What am I doing wrong setting the test suite up?

Isn't the idea of beforeAll() to allow costy calls like `module('app')` to be only made once?

Below is one of my simple tests, which runs at the state I posted it, so my question is simply about the cost of calling the module multiple times :S

```
/* jshint -W117, -W030 */
describe('blocks.filter.dateFormatter', function() {

    var filter, cacheFactory;

    //beforeAll(function() {
    //    module('app');
    //});
    // Code above leads to unknown provider error

    beforeEach(function() {
        module('app');
        inject(['$filter', 'CacheFactory',
            function($filter, $CacheFactory) {
                filter = $filter;
                cacheFactory = $CacheFactory;
                cacheFactory.destroyAll();
            }
        ]);
    });

    it('dateFormatter convert yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss to dd.MM.yyyy', function() {
        expect(filter('formatDate')('2015-09-28 00:00:00')).toBe('28.09.2015');
    });

    it('dateFormatter convert yyyy-MM-dd to dd.MM.yyyy', function() {
        expect(filter('formatDate')('1960-05-05')).toBe('05.05.1960');
    });

});
```

Yes I know, the problem with the cache is solved ugly but I did lose patience with it :)

Any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the module by itself shouldn't be that big of a performance hit (did you measure it?), but if you want to use `beforeAll()` you should use `module.sharedInjector()`. Look for "Using beforeAll" in [this page](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/unit-testing).